# PHP mail function is not working on my server?

Tags: php, email

My mail function is on online server. It was working fine. But not now. I am confused why it has stopped sending mail. It shows the message that email sent, but no email is received in inbox.

**Here is my php code:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    $headers = "From: " . $email . "\n"; //from address
    $to = ""; //my mail id
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1 \n";
    $subject = "Test mail";

    $body = '<html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title>"."<h3>"."Hello Test,."</h3>".
    </title>
        </head>
        <body><p></p>
            <p style="color: #00CC66; font-weight:600; font-style:italic; font-size:14px; float:left; margin-left:7px;">You have received an inquiry from your website.  Please review the contact information below.

    :</p>';
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
        ?>
        <h3 style="color:#d96922; font-weight:bold; height:0px; margin-top:1px;">Thank You For Contacting us!!</h3>

        <?php
    } else {

        print_r(error_get_last());
    }
}
```

What's wrong with it? Please help me to find out the solution. And also help me to echo error?

Comment: Can't find your `mail()` code anywhere ....

Comment: i update the code please help me for this issue..it's very urgent..

Comment: seems that you have a configured mail server in your server?

Comment: Could be lots of things.  I'm assuming you are getting no errors?  It could be your spam filter or your server is queueing the messages.

Comment: @Priyajain, Did you check your spam folders ?

Comment: this question suppose to be asked with your hosting service provider...

Comment: Yes i have checked on my spam folder..i don't found any mail...:(

Comment: how can get the error message to caught an error?

Comment: Are you using Godaddy server ? sometimes it takes upto 8 hours to receive the emails.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'd give this a try, ending each line with `\r\n` and also adding a *To* header (redundant as it might seem). Also, declaring `charset=utf-8` in the header should be enough. If not though, make sure it matches (right now there's a mismatch).

```
<?php
  $subject = "Test mail";
  $to_email = "to@example.com";
  $to_fullname = "John Doe";
  $from_email = "from@example.com";
  $from_fullname = "Jane Doe";
  $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
  $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
  // Additional headers
  // This might look redundant but some services REALLY favor it being there.
  $headers .= "To: $to_fullname <$to_email>\r\n";
  $headers .= "From: $from_fullname <$from_email>\r\n";
  $message = "<html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" lang=\"en\" xml:lang=\"en\">\r\n
  <head>\r\n
    <title>Hello Test</title>\r\n
  </head>\r\n
  <body>\r\n
    <p></p>\r\n
    <p style=\"color: #00CC66; font-weight:600; font-style: italic; font-size:14px; float:left; margin-left:7px;\">You have received an inquiry from your website.  Please review the contact information below.</p>\r\n
  </body>\r\n
  </html>";
  if (!mail($to_email, $subject, $message, $headers)) { 
    print_r(error_get_last());
  }
  else { ?>
    <h3 style="color:#d96922; font-weight:bold; height:0px; margin-top:1px;">Thank You For Contacting us!!</h3>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
```

I'd also replace the first line with something like this, to avoid notices / errors:

```
if ($_POST && isset($_POST['submit']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Working with godadday server it works as expected, but on bigrock server it will not work till we did not create a respond mail ( registered mail from cpanel). Login to your cpanel provided by big rock, scroll down to register a mail id. create that mail id e.g no-reply@your-domain.com.

Once you will create that mail id wait for 10-30 minutes after that mail function will start working.

for more details [read this article](https://support.bigrock.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/873/9/using-a-php-email-script)

Answer (score -1):

Had a similar challenge, on my end however the error was not on the code, i had missed creating the actual sent from email on cpanel. Its an easy thing to miss but can frustrate you